# Debugging MVC site VS15

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just downloaded Visual Studio 15 Preview 5 and created an MVC application, attempting to follow [this tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc.html). So I hit F5 to launch, and I get the following:

[image]

Nothing ever happens. Is there something in the setup that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

your startup url path is incorrect, also check the route of mvc application.